# HTML/Javascript + CSVs - Using filters vs. Loading many CSVs

Tags: javascript, csv, web

I'm thinking about what is the best way to feed a chart with filtered data. The thing is that I have year and month filters among others and I want the chart to be **quick on showing up** and **switching data on filter change**.

Is it better to prepare already filtered data into individual CSVs and load them from server as needed or should I use Javascript to filter data on client side using a big CSV?

Individual files:
- Load quickly
- No client-side computations

Big CSV:
- Avoids network connection (loaded once)

If I choose individual files I would have A LOT of them as filters create many combinations. I don't know if there is any drawback in that case. I think the individual files are the option with the highest performance.

Comment: You're almost certainly not displaying a grid of data.  If you're talking about a chart, then you really only need two fields, one for x-axis and one for y-axis.  The client optimizes by receiving and processing *only what is necessary* and the server optimizes by minimizing request time, in this case perhaps by preparing the csv to send and keeping them ready to send to client if a similar request is sent.  If anything, the server filters the data by year or month, but I would compare with directly taking data from database for times.

Comment: The CSVs would be prepared before the user calls for data, so there is no database access. The problem is if it is better to get the full CSV of data and show it filtered on the client or ask for filtered data directly to the server.

Comment: The short answer is that it depends on how much data you're talking about and if that is likely to change for the worse.  The safe money is on letting the server deal with it.

Comment: Is it not an important drawback to depend on network connection to load data filtered by the server? The data volume is low, so maybe it is possible to filter it on client-side, but I would like to keep the client light so that if the data grows I can prevent client overload...

Comment: You're sending data on every page load, but assuming your charts are not extremely populated, it is a reasonable thing to do.  If you think it isn't too much information to save client-side, you could anticipate say, next and previous months so that if user clicks on them, you don't need to have the user wait.  However in order to make that work well, you'd need to have only a "next" and "previous" month link and not jump around.

Comment: I need to make it possible to select any years and month. I think it won't be a problem to filter client-side as the data is not very big. The only problem could arise when the CSV is big enough to slow down the charts first loading.